# Custom DataView Grid Control

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, grid, formatting

I need to create a custom data grid view control to solve tailored for my needs.

Presently I am binding the dataset to a grid and I need to check the data in the grid and format some values or clear the cells and make the color of the cell gray (Disabled.). This takes a huge time when the data increases to a couple of thousand rows.

So I thought that if I can create a custom datagrid which has these properties the time taken will be reduced as the the formatting of the grid cells will happen instantly.

Can some one help me out with this if this is possible.I need to do this in VB.net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DataGridView.CellFormatting` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx). This event occurs when a cell has to be formatted for display. Rows that are "hidden" won't have this event being called upon.

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
    Handles dataGridView1.CellFormatting
    '-----------------------------------
    ' Do my magic
End Sub
```

Normally you don't have to create a custom control to do this. Just wire up the event.

Comment: Hi Styxx, Got it to work I used the following lines of code below. DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("F2").Style.BackColor = Color.Gray, DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("F2").Value = DBNull.Value

Comment: How to make this datagrid to stop this event.. when I look at it it keeps looping thruough the grid. is there any way To make sure it just does only one pass of the grid.